# Two action in one button form

Tags: java, html, forms, button, action

Is there a way to have a button call a method from java and executed it also after it executes it goes to a new page in the browser

```
                    <div class="link">
                        <form action="/sendSMS" method="GET">
                            <h2>
                                <label> Send a message: </label>
                            </h2>
                            <button class="gradient-button gradient-button-2" onclick="snedSMS()"> Send </button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
            <!--  End of send SMS -->
```

Currently, this button calls a method in my java application and executes it, but when it executes it goes to a blank page. I want it to go to either a new page or redirect it to the same page the button was on.

Comment: Have you using AJAX? it's a better way to send data to your backend and won't redirect user

Comment: Hi @Maiz - do you mean javascript not java? [if so tags might be wrong?]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the limited information you give I am guessing that the core issue is that you need to add type="button" attribute to your button to prevent the default submit action. This removes the default behavior of the button which is submit. Assuming you are using fetch or an ajax call inside the sendSMS function, you will need to handle your redirect inside the callback there.

```
<button type="button" class="gradient-button gradient-button-2" onclick="snedSMS()"> Send </button>
```

I am also guessing that the onclick handler in your button is a typo. Should it be sendSMS()?